# Google provide JSON form query result?

Tags: json, google-search, web-mining

I am doing some web mining tasks using Google.

Though using the ordinary Google search engine might help, I still need to analyse the web pages.

I want to ask:

Does Google provide query results in JSON form?

**PS:**

I know [one place,Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/), but the query amount for free user is limited, which can not satisfy my need.

So, anyone know other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not provide search results in JSON format unless you use the custom search API.

Answer (score 1):

A 'Bing search engine'  query can be run through a Yahoo Pipe and posted out as JSON.